# gmaps api does not work on python

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to imply google map on my jupyter notebook. My environment is OSX and using `conda` distribution python mainly.

I see `gmaps` in conda list and pip list and I can successfully import `gmaps`.
However, I cannot call `configure`.

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key="AI...")

fig = gmaps.figure()
fig
```

Then I got this error message.

```
AttributeError: module 'gmaps' has no attribute 'configure'
```

How can I figure out this issue?

Thanks!